# How to determine if a PR build is from origin repo source vs repo fork

Tags: teamcity

When using TeamCity and enabling builds for PRs via the GitHub plugin, how can one determine if the build is originated from a PR from a fork vs a PR branched off of the original repo in Github?

How can one determine if the PR is to be trusted or be able to disable PR builds from untrusted forks?